# What is the word that means "the feeling of the scene"?

Tags: single-word-requests

i.e., the atmosphere, but in a more encompassing sense of things. The bustling sights, sounds, and scents, the sweet feeling of a day, a carnival on the plains at sunset. Or even a gestalt impression of an event over 60 long days, the general feel of that period compressed into a single scene.

 I vaguely remember it like "siouziánne" or "soucienne" (nonsense word, but it had a similar feel... maybe French.)